# Out of memory error: vast bitmap

Tags: android, memory

My activity has listview and (apart from all other stuff) loads images from web and displays them in listview. I have access to 5 android devices: 2 HTC desire, LG P-350, one more phone and a tablet. Normally, everything works fine, but being launched on one of HTC desire, app tends to crash with NullPointerException, which is due to out of memory error (I guess so), this is the output:

```
05-03 14:41:23.818: E/dalvikvm(843): Out of memory: Heap Size=7367KB, Allocated=4991KB, Bitmap Size=16979KB
```

Later, logcat outputs stack trace of nullpointerexception where one of my static variables suddenly becomes null (the variable is initialized in app's root activity, is used across the app and for sure is not nulled in code). I suppose, it is nulled by system due to lack of memory.
As far as I undesrstand, system tries to allocate bitmap as large as 17mb - I'm sure loaded images cant be that big. They are 100*70 jpegs and any of them weighs far less than 1mb.
Another thing I dont understand is why I get this error only on one device - other devices work fine.

To my mind, this looks very strange and I can find no clue, I need advice.

Comment: 1 Image size is less than 1MB and so if you add all the images size then it will be a big enough to give you OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Btw: No system nulls your variables. Either your code puts a `null` or the variable is not initialized yet. The only variables where that could happen are those that are explicitly made for that: weak/soft references.

Comment: My listview is organized in a way that item click starts a new activity (let it be activity B). I set breakpoint in listview's onItemClick, run app in debug mode, enter listview activity, press listview item, stop at breakpoint, examine static variable's value - it is not null. Then I place breakpoint in B's onCreate, executing stops there, I examine the same static variable's value - it is already null. Is it magic? I have no my code between listview item click listener and B's oncreate. The variable is nulled somewhere between these two points...

Comment: 2 Dharmendra: if allocation of all my bitmaps results in OutOfMemoryError, why logcat outputs "Bitmap Size=16979KB"? Doesn't it mean a single bitmap to be that big?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple: the memory is not holding your JPG data per say, but rather its decompressed equivalent, which, needless to say, takes a lot more RAM space than the source files... Note that this 17 mb limit is for all your loaded bitmaps at once, not necessarily a single one.

I had to fight with similar problems in one of my programs (a custom Tile loader for a Mapquest Android API MapView object), and I ended up having to call the `recycle()` method of my bitmaps whenever possible, as well as manually oblige the system to garbage collect at strategic locations using `System.gc()`...

Sorry to not be the bearer of the best news...

You might solve your problems using the same strategy as I did: I essentially cache the loaded bitmaps in hard storage such as my external SD card, and reload them on the fly when needed, instead of attempting to hold everything in RAM.

Comment: If the crash is due to big bitmap size, how can everything be ok on other devices (one of them is another HTC desire)?

Comment: I think that there isn't a standard max RAM footprint size fixed for all Android devices. For instance, I had a roughly 17 mb max footprint for my own HTC Desire running Android 2.1, but my Acer Iconia tablet needed more strain on resources to crash as well.  Anyone can confirm this with some official docs? Note: is your 2nd Desire device running on exactly the same OS Version?

Comment: This is a kernel limit, eg dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit which can be changed in build.prop.
On older device (or device with low memory) it was set to 16 or 24Mb. On recent devices it is set to 64Mb.